# How automatically to see traffic for each post in Jekyll blog?

Tags: google-analytics, github-pages, jekyll

I recently migrated to Jekyll from WordPress / Blogger and what I miss most is easy traffic statistics.

I embed Google Analytics code into Jekyll, but I can only see overall traffic. When I want to see traffic to a specific post, I have to go into Google Analytics and create a Segment.

This is much more inconvenient than WordPress / Blogger, in which there's Statistics for each of the posts ready to be seen.

Is it possible to do the same for Jekyll + Google Analytics?